# after successful login the user is redirected to the home page where the SPA loads. Is using session cookie with JWT a bad idea?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I have an express + postgres backend, and I'm using passport-facebook for FB oauth.

If a user hits my app at `/` without having a valid token in localStorage, they're taken to `/login`.

My `/login` page (where you're greeted with the familiar "Continue with Facebook" message) is server rendered (for various reasons).  Upon clicking this button, I either verify the user if they exist and send them a session cookie with the initial JWT, or create a new user and send them a session cookie with the initial JWT.  In both cases, the success condition is that they are redirected to `/` and served the SPA assets.

One of the first things the SPA does is take the JWT from the session cookie and put it into localstorage, and then deletes the cookie.

Is this a terrible approach, or is it valid in my use case?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the session cookie as a means to store the JWT on the client. This means that you create a server session that will remain open until it expires, by spending server resources

Session cookies are not readable from javascript, so I guess you make a request to the server to get the JWT, right?

The process does not seem problematic, but I think you could optimize it by sending in your redirection process directly the JWT in the response using a regular cookie with  `set-cookie` header. The cookie will be stored in client and you could access it directly

Comment: thanks.  I am doing `res.cookie('auth', req.token)`.  Is that considered a session cookie, or am I using terms wrong?  I'm not passing any options, and I want the cookie to disappear when the user closes their browser.

Comment: No, this is a usual cookie that won't create a session in your server. You didn't set the expiry, so the cookie will disappear after restarting browser. This is how I was proposing to do it